# PHP header() doesnt redirects after ajax is called

Tags: php, ajax

I am using ajax to insert data. after registration if successful it will redirect to its registry page or registry.php. But it seems that it is not redirecting to its respective page and the weird thing is when i check it on the console on firefox it seems that it gives a right result, something like this POST xxxx/form_zuri/insertData.php 302 Found
50ms and GET xxxx/form_zuri/registry.php 302 Found 37ms.

heres the code for insertData.php

```
    if($data = $admin->insertRegistrantInfo($fname, $lname, $aname, $email, $password) == true) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);// destroying the old session id and creating a new one
    $_SESSION['id'] =  $data;
    header('location: registry.php');
    exit();
```

heres my ajax script:

```
$("#submit_third").click(function(){


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insertData.php",
        data: {

            fname                       : $("#fname").val(),
            lname                       : $("#lname").val(),
            aname                       : $("#aname").val(),                
            email                       : $("#email").val(),
            password                    : $("#password").val()              

            },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {

        //window.location.replace('registry.php') ;   

        }
    });
    //window.location.replace('registry.php') ;  
    //return false;

});
```

if i will use the .replace js function it wont be able to get the SESSION ID.

any idea guys?

Comment: No you can't redirect like that you need to send an id to your response and on that response you need to check that id in your ajax response and in this section you will redirect your page using jquery.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for!! how you solved this @user3052545

Answer (score 7):

When you call a PHP Script in AJAX, the request is being executed by the AJAX call and not the current page the client is on, therefore it won't change the headers on the page that is actually being viewed - only on the response of the AJAX call. Which in this case won't do what you want.

Also, you can't change the headers when content has already been outputted which again in your case it will have been.

If you use `window.location.href = 'registry.php'` in your AJAX callback, the session id should be there. Using `window.location.replace` won't add a new record to your history.

Comment: thanks for the answer @Stanyer but it gives me error TypeError: window.location.href is not a function
window.location.href('registry.php') ;

Comment: The `window.location.href` is a JavaScript function to be called in the AJAX callback, where you currently have `window.location.replace` commented out.

Comment: i actually used the window.location.href

Comment: As mentioned in a different answer, try `location.reload();` after.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach will be to create another session id, for example $_SESSION["passed"] = true; then after successful insert of your data you can refreshes your current page, and still use the header method.

php code

```
if (isset($_SESSION["passed"])){
if ($_SESSION["passed"]) header('location: registry.php');
}
```

on the javascript side you can reload after a successful query

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: `code`if($data = $admin->getSessionID($email) == true);
   $_SESSION['id'] =  $data;
  header('location: registry.php');
  exit();    i added this and laso the reload function it redirect me to the form itself again..

Comment: where did you place the header statement, The header statement has to be before any output to the screen otherwise it will not work.

Comment: what do you mean?if($data = $admin->insertRegistrantInfo($fname, $lname, $aname, $email, $password) == true) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);// destroying the old session id and creating a new one
    $_SESSION['id'] =  $data;
    header('location: registry.php');
    exit();

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect in that way in php file.You need to set any variable in response 
and in your ajax success box you can maintain a check if that particular value set 
you will redirect your page using Jquery.

And I don't think it make any issue in SESSION you must need to call session_start() on header of your page.

Comment: Try print_r($_SESSION);exit  after $_SESSION['id'] =  $data; this code and check session value set perfectly or not.Also check your redirect code it must be window.location.href='registry.php';