# I don't understand how ob_start() and ob_end_clean()

Tags: php, jquery

Please be patient with me. I've been spending 1 hour on internet trying to look for a solution, but nothing seems working. And yet I thought I understood how it works.

I'm hosting my website on Altervista. What I would like to do is the following: I send login credentials, if there is some problem, echo an error message (depending on the type of error), else go to the home page:

**process_info.php**

```
<?php

    ob_start();

    if($_POST["nickname"] and $_POST["password"]) {
        $username = $_POST["nickname"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Please fill the form";
        exit();
    }

    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, "db");

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        echo "Connection failed"; // $conn->connect_error
    }

    $conn->close();

    session_start();
    $_SESSION["nickname"] = $username;
    $_SESSION["password"] = $password;

    ob_end_clean();

    header("location: ../interno/home/home.php");
    exit();

?>
```

This is how I send the login information in my **login.php**:

```
<script>


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#invia").click(function(){

            var n = $("#nickname").val();
            var p = $("#password").val();

            $.post("php/invia_credenziali.php",
            {
              nickname: n,
              password: p
            },

            function(data,status){
                //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                window.alert(data);
            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

But my browser doesn't jump to home. Instead I get the window.alert message.

How can I solve this?

Comment: ob_end_clean(); should be placed before exit;

Comment: Your use of these functions appears to be to cover up the oft seen content sent before headers warning. Try fixing it instead of working around it :)

Comment: And why are you redirecting with PHP after logged in? You can achieve it by javascript also window.location.href="";

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975546/php-header-doesnt-redirects-after-ajax-is-called

Comment: Wait a minute.... WTF?!? You try to connect to the database server using credentials provided in a http post? So client side specified credentials? That is insane!

Comment: @RahulPatel I placed ob_end_clean() before exit. It doesn't work anyway :(

I thought about redirecting with javascript, but by now I dig my heels in! I would like to understand why I doesn't work >_<

Comment: @arkascha What? Could you give me some context about it? It seems that you have something to learn me. I'm a noob.

Comment: The credentials used to connect to the database server are constant. They belong into the code or some configuration file. It is your application authenticating itself. Your users credentials are something completely different! You use those in a subsequent query to the database to check against a user table! So you have one mysql account used by your application and multiple users you store in and identify against a table inside some database in that mysql server.

Comment: @arkascha Let me understand what you mean. Do you advice me to create a table with all users? Should I access my DB as root and then query the DB to login? It seems a different approach, but the result seems the same. Moreover, my web site will be used just by one person. Or maybe did I misunderstand what you wrote?

Comment: @RahulPatel I have one more question. If I used javascrit, shouldn't there be some security problem if they use URL to jump to the home page or are session variables enough to avoid unauthorized access?

Comment: You connect to your database server using a single, non priviliged accound. So not root, but a normal account inside that database server. Inside your applications database you have a table for user accounts. That gives you two flexibilities: 1) you can store profile information for the users, 2) your application can manage the user accounts which is mot possible if you want to use separate database accounts for all your users.

Comment: The difference in the two approaches, your being extremely exotic, never heard of auch a strategy... The difference is security and flexibility.

Comment: @arkascha , understood. Thank you for the explanation!

But if I have, let's suppose, this query to check if that user exist, like:

SELECT * FROM Users WHERE nickname=$nickname AND password=$password

Am I not vulnerable to SQL Injection? I've read a lot about this problem. I read that I need to use marker @ to solve this problem, but I didn't understand that well how to use it. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Every query you run against your database is potentially insecure and attackable by means of sql injection. However the answer to that is not to hesitate and try to get around queries, but to secure them which indeed is possible. That is true for each and ever query you implement. You need to use the combination of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding". The mysqli extension allows that. Done right this offers reliable protection against such attacks. There are many examples of how to do that.

Comment: Plus there is another issue you have to take care of: you _never_ store a user password inside a database. Never. What you store is a hash of a password. Then, at authorization time you again hash the submitted password and compare both hashes. That way your users passwords do not get compromised even if your system is hacked. There are ready to be used implementation fire this. Take care to use a good hashing algoruthm with salt.

Comment: @arkascha wow! Thanks for the good advices! I will treasure them :)

Comment: BTW: this is what I used in some projects for password hashing and maintenance: https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm