# PHP Login Page Redirect Does Not Load New Page

Tags: php, html

I have this php script to redirect the user to the html file of the main page if the username and password are correct. However, when this code is executed, the html file only shows up as a new resource but the page does not load. I am not sure how to get the page to load when using the header function.

```html
<?php
$password2 = $_POST['password1'];
$username2 = $_POST['username1'];
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "database") or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");  
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users where username = '$username2' AND password = '$password2'") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_BOTH) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
if(!empty($row['username']) AND !empty($row['password'])) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username2;
    header('Location: http://localhost/application/site.html');
    echo "Successful Login"; 
    exit;
}
else{
    echo "The password or username you have entered is not valid";
}
mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean as shows up as a new resource?

Comment: You should use `die();` right after `header()`. You do not want to `echo "Successful Login";` since the header is meant to redirect the user, that line will never be seen.

Comment: When using the developer console on a web browser, the site.html file shows up when the php script is executed. However, the login page does not change into the page for site.html.

Comment: What do you mean by "the site.html file shows up". How are you loading this page and submitting your data (form, xhr/ajax?).

Comment: Under the resources tab in the Javascript console for Safari, the site.html pops up when the script is run but the page itself does not load. I am using ajax to submit the data.

Comment: have you added a <?php session_start(); ?> at the top of the page site.html? I not sure if you have a condition there that if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){ //goto login}

Comment: The Location header doesn't work over ajax. On successful authentication you'll need to set window.location = 'http://localhost/application/site.html' in the javascript that submits the ajax request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP header() doesnt redirects after ajax is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975546/php-header-doesnt-redirects-after-ajax-is-called)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment:

> Under the resources tab in the Javascript console for Safari, the
>   site.html pops up when the script is run but the page itself does not
>   load. I am using ajax to submit the data

The Location header **is not honored** when sent in an ajax request.

You should update your code that submits the ajax request to redirect the page on successful authentication.

For example you'll want to do something like the following (in jQuery):

```
$.post('/path/to/login.php', {username: '...', password: '...'})
     .success(function(response){  
       if (response.status == 403) {
          // show error message to user
       } else {
          window.location = 'http://localhost/application/site.html';
       }
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR) {
        // show error message to user
    });
```

You'll want to return authentication status from your php script, something like the following:

```
<?php
$password2 = $_POST['password1'];
$username2 = $_POST['username1'];
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "database") or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");  
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users where username = '$username2' AND password = '$password2'") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_BOTH) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
if(!empty($row['username']) AND !empty($row['password'])) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username2;
    http_response_code(200);
    echo "Successful Login";
    exit;
}
else{
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "The password or username you have entered is not valid";
}
mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the top of the page

ob_start();

And at the bottom of page add the

ob_end_flush();

Header in php always run before any output occurs.
So turn on output buffering